# Is there any System Function/Object to retrieve the CName when connected to SSMS using it

Tags: sql-server, ssms, cname

When CName is used to connect to SQL Server in SSMS, none of the System Functions return the CName but actual Physical name is returned.

```
`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName'), SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'), @@SERVERNAME ,SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')`
```

Example: For server DW01 that is hosting SQL Server Instance, CName SQLQA is created. We are connecting to the SQL Server instance using SQLQA but all the above functions show up DW01 instead of SQLQA.

Can someone tell me if there is any way in SQL Server to know this.

Comment: *"Can someone tell me if there is any way in SQL Server to know this."* SQL Server will not be aware of the CName is it given. A CName is an alias in the network's DNS, which directs the connection to the true name of the server. The Server doesn't "know" what it's been aliased as on the network; not using the inbuilt functions anyway. The functions above return information about the server itself; not it's "domain name". That doesn't mean you couldn't create a CLI function to query the DNS and find out.

Comment: It is disappointing because I want to record in the screenshots which server am connected to using these functions. SQL Server should record it.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't say you couldn't get it, but those functions are not for returning a list of CName aliases. They tell you details about the server itself.